# Return to the previous page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a search text input in my layout page in a partialView and other 3 pages that uses layout:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Product"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchText)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SearchText)

    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
}
```

When it goes inside Product/Search action, how can I know where it came from and return to the correct page with a message assuming the 3 other pages uses different ViewModels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout, modify your `BeginForm` to include the request path in the route values:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Product"),new {path = Request.Path})
```

Then, in your controller, you can finish up by redirecting to that path:

```
public ActionResult Search( string path, FormCollection form ) {
    // build your search results here
    return Redirect( path );
}
```

And that should do the trick.  If you need to pass additional information along, you can just append a query string to the path:

```
public ActionResult Search( string path, FormCollection form ) {
    // build your search results here
    return Redirect( path + "?message=foo" );
}
```

Comment: Nice.. but I need to show a message saying something goes wrong, how can I redirect with a message?

Comment: and can I clear the url after redirect? because is added a query string in url.

Comment: I edited the post to show how you can pass a message along.  I'm not sure what you mean by "clear the URL after redirect," though.

Comment: When I submit, my url will be http://localhost:58205/Product/Search?path=%2FProduct%2FSearch... I want to clear this '?path=xxxxx'

Comment: Since this issues a HTTP 302 redirect, the URL will not appear in the browser's URL location bar.

Comment: But it is ocurring when I do search and return the correct view with results. I want to clear the path parameter in this moment.